# SQL Server - Quebra de Linha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia, obrigado pelo tempo em ler essa duvida.

Problema !

---

Considera a linha de registro

`ID | Nome 
1  | "Fulano 1, Fulano 2, Fulano 3, Fulano 4"`

Preciso montar um select que ao resultar, retorne:

`ID | Nome 
1  | "Fulano 1"
1  | "Fulano 2"
1  | "Fulano 3"
1  | "Fulano 4"`

Tem outros detalhes que irei ter que me virar ainda rsrsrs, pois essa virgula foi somente um exemplo básico que dei, pois terei de enfrentar outros problemas como  char(13), apenas espaços, nomenclaturas "ou", exemplo:

`ID | Nome 
1  | "Fulano 1**char(13)** Fulano 2**char(13)** Fulano 3 **char(13)** Fulano 4"
2  | "Fulano 1       Fulano 2      Fulano 3"
3  | "Fulano 1 **ou** Fulano 2"`

PS. A Quantidade de nome por registro é variável, conforme exemplos

Peço desculpas caso a duvida não tenha ficado clara.
Agradeço a todos.

Comment: qual a versão do SQL Server está usando?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, SQL Server 2014!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar esta função de acordo com seu delimitador ('**',',',..)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SDF_SplitString]
(
    @sString nvarchar(2048),
    @cDelimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE ( part nvarchar(2048) )
AS
BEGIN
    if @sString is null return
    declare @iStart int,
            @iPos int
    if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
    begin
        set @iStart = 2
        insert into @tParts
        values( null )
    end
    else 
        set @iStart = 1
    while 1=1
    begin
        set @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
        if @iPos = 0
            set @iPos = len( @sString )+1
        if @iPos - @iStart > 0          
            insert into @tParts
            values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
        else
            insert into @tParts
            values( null )
        set @iStart = @iPos+1
        if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
            break
    end
    RETURN

END
```

A partir da versão 2016 já tem disponível a função [string_split()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Caro amigo, agradeço muito sua ajuda. Não resolveu o problema por inteiro porem tenho um ótimo local de partida agora.

Comment: Como você tem registros em que o delimitador pode mudar (espaços ou **), neste caso você precisa utilizar um "CASE WHEN" com a função CHARINDEX para verificar se há ou não aquele caracter.